# how to use date_part in hibernate query?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

```
String q = "select id from Calendar c " +
    "where c.isActive = 1 and " +
    "date_part('dow', '2017-09-19 13:23:23'::date) = c.frequencyValue)";
Query query = em.createQuery(q);
List results = query.getResultList();
```

If I include `::date`, hibernate would complain because `:` conflicts with parameter, but if I don't, postgres will complain. `Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.` What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions

as specified extract function should work if the underlying db supports them so:

```
 extract(dow from date '2017-09-19 13:23:23');
```

should works